# something wrong with jbpm and kie server

Tags: maven, jboss, jbpm, kie

I want use jbpm6's rest interface,so i installed the kie. I put the kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee7.war in the deployments folder and new the hibernate.properties in the jbpm-installer folder.Then i command `./add-user.sh -a -u admin -p admin -g admin,kie-server` and `standalone.sh  -c standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.id=hello-kie-server -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee7/services/rest/server`.But it failed.the errors are:

```
 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) Error when initializing server extension of type jBPM KIE Server extension: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create EntityManagerFactory due to [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.domain] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/ExampleDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS
```

(all ExampleDS have change to jbpmDS)

```
ERROR [org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error during create repository: java.lang.RuntimeException: https://github.com/guvnorngtestuser1/jbpm-console-ng-playground-kjar.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
```

(I don't kown which file use the address?)

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service    
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:Exception 0 :org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground()org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup@3d037714
```

I want open web http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/ but it failed. it means the kie server start failed? I don't kown why?